# Search a specific text within a cell and return a matched text from a list

Tags: excel

I cannot figure out how to make the below formula work - it always results in an `#N/A`. I'm trying to search in a cell for certain text from a list and return when a match is found another text from a list.

!(https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMrqey3My-qDeMlFSWoNmvyp39lo8H5Q8Fl_k4)

I tried `vlookup`, and want to avoid the usage of if (the complete list is about 40+ countries) but cannot make it work a `index`, `search` and `isnumber`.

My end result would be the following : search the cell "Singapore FSS", have the formula recognize "Singapore" and return  the value of "ASE"

```
=INDEX(D1:E4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,D1:D4)),0),MATCH("text to return",D1:E1,0))
```

Thank you in advance for your help and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the logic:

1. We have cells to be processed and a table with cities/codes to be found and return
2. Build an array of indices of found cities using `SEARCH` function (this array will contain either index or `#VALUE!` if city isn't found)
3. Find the position of a non-error element (Ok, I consider, that there's only one match, so we return the first one) using `MATCH` function
4. Find the value to return using obtained relative position

Here's my sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Here's the function. It should be **array-formula** to properly build array of indices (create it for the first cell using **Ctrl-Shift-Enter**)

```
{=INDEX($E$1:$E$4;MATCH(1;SEARCH($D$1:$D$4;A1);-1))}
```

Then simply drag it, or use Excel Tables.

The result:

[image]

Comment: спасибо! it worked very well. Thanks for the great help